# Do liquid O₂ and N₂ form ideal solutions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics

I suspect they do, but could not find data on this. (I mean at temperatures near those used in the distillation of liquid air.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not perfectly ideal.  Try to get access to [Excess enthalpies of the liquid mixtures nitrogen + oxygen...](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021961475900944) for quantitative data.